# Book about Rabbis and Zionism

Tags: history, jewish-books, zionism

What is a good book which goes into detail about Rabbis (particularly those living in Israel from 1880-1950) and their personal experience with Zionists and the Palestinians?

I am particularly interested in learning about their (Torah) views on Zionism, their intervention with Jewish extremism, and the personal relations and diplomatic efforts they had attempted with the native Arab population and Muslim leaders of Palestine during the tumultuous decades leading up to 1948.

Comment: I have asked my father, who has done a fair bit of reading on the subject if knows any titles. I will try to get an answer from him b"n.

Comment: I am not sure you will like the content but there is a good book called "דת הציונות" summing up views of Zionism in the eyes of many important Rabbis (it does not however deal with any particular view of the Palestinians)

Comment: They were tumultuous times, life was hard, I don't think people were writing books about their social engagements with this or that group. And a minor point that doesn't answer your question. You say arab populatio.  I think prior to arab nationalism (Which started after modern Zionism,e.g. arab nationalism started in the 1920s rather than 1880s).. The people didn't consider or weren't considered arabs. They were arabic speaking tribes in the levant. Prior to arab nationalism, Arabs were just in arabia

Comment: I am not interested about views on Zionism (which is a side point). I want to read about Rabbis who actually dealt with the Zionists and Palestinians and how they viewed and dealt with the situation. It's sad how if I write Torah view on Zionism and Palestinian in one question, I get answers about the anti-Zionists. That is not my intent. I will decide for myself what is the proper view on the early Zionists. Right now, I want to read about the history of the region from the perspective of the Rabbis (particularly those living in Palestine) who dealt with the people involved.

Comment: @EinbertAlshtein: Thanks. Would you care to summarize the book: Where he lived, why he changed his views, and why the Rabbis held what they held.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Have you had a chance to talk to your father yet? I'm very interested to hear his knowledge...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky, not at length, although I have sent him an email with this question, so be"h he'll reply soon.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt: danke! :)

Comment: @Emetv'Shalom - I don't understand the connection you have made between Zionism and the Palestinians, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Until 1950 (and even later) the Palestinians were the Jews living in what is now Israel (e.g., the Bank of Palestine was a Jewish bank). Is this what you mean? Or do you mean the Arabs living in what is now Israel?